# How to find the probability mass function and mean of a function Y of binomial random variable X.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-distribution, random-functions

So, suppose I have a binomial random variable $X$ with parameters $n=6$ and $p=(1/5)$. Now, if I have a function of $X$ like $Y=(X-2)^2$, how do I go about finding it's properties - and in particular, $P(Y=y), P(Y<y)$ and $E[Y]$?

In the case of a continuous random variable, I would use the distribution function or change-of-variable techniques to find the CDF or PDF of $Y$, but in this case $X$ is a (discrete) binomial random variable. Furthermore, $Y$ is two-to-one, which further complicates things.

All I've figured out is that $Y$ should share the same parameter *p* as $X$ (I think?) and that the space of $Y$ in this case should be:

$Y \in (1,4,9,16)$ since $X \in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and $Y=(X-2)^2$.

Is the mean of $Y$ (or $E[Y]$) still equal to $np$? How do I find it's PMF? How would I go about evaluating $P(Y<y)$?

Just some guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get $P(Y=y)$ you can get $P(Y<y)$ and $E[Y]$, so i'll give you a hint for getting $P(Y=y)$.

$P(X=0) = (4/5)^6$, $P(X=4) = 15(1/5)^4(4/5)^2$.

Now,

$Y=4$ iff $X=0$ or $X=4$, so $P(Y=4) = P(X=0) + P(X=4)$

Also $Y$ can take the value $0$ if $X=2$

Comment: Hmmm... okay, I've gotten this: $P(Y=y)=\binom{6}{{\sqrt y}+2}(\frac15)^{\sqrt y + 2}(\frac45)^{6-(\sqrt y + 2)} + \binom{6}{{-\sqrt y}+2}(\frac15)^{-\sqrt y + 2}(\frac45)^{6-(-\sqrt y + 2)}$

So, for $P(Y=4)$:

$P(Y=4)=\binom{6}{4}(\frac15)^4(\frac45)^2 + \binom{6}{0}(\frac15)^0(\frac45)^6\approx$ .2775

Does that look right?

Comment: And what about the mean? Is it still equal to $np$ as is generally the case for binomial random variables? 

Should I calculate all the probabilities and then sum $y*P(y)$? That would give me the mean but seems labor intensive.

Comment: Hint: ${\mathsf E(Y)~{=~\mathsf E((X-2)^2)\\=~\mathsf E(X^2-4X+4)}}$

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for that. I saw that earlier but wasn't sure what to do with it. If I think about trying to calculate $E[X^2-4X+4]$ by multiplying $X^2-4X+4$ and the binomial PMF by hand it seems extremely tedious.

Comment: Yes, so 0.2775 if y = 4 (that is a part of your PDF), you have to compute the other values that can take $Y$. And for the hint of Graham, remember that $E(X)$ is a linear function.